# EF repository validation failing for unknown reason

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I have two tables, User and UserPhoto which are expressed with a One-to-Many relationship. I want to have a UserRepository class that has AddUser/UpdateUser/DeleteUser methods, and also AddUserPhoto and DeleteUserPhoto because there is some logic I would like to implement aroudn the addition and deletion of user photos that I want contained in the repository layer.

In the AddUserPhoto method, I retrieve the User object from the set, add the photo, set modified to true and return the validation result. As below

```
public bool AddUserPhoto(DbUserPhoto photo, object userId)
        {
            try
            {
                var dbItem = Context.Users.Find(userId);
                if (dbItem == null) 
                   throw new Exception(string.Format("User id {0} not found"
                                                     , userId));

                // Some logic around ordering of photos and only having 
                //one primary photo
                if (photo.IsPrimary)
                {
                    foreach (var p in dbItem.Photos)
                    {
                        p.IsPrimary = false;
                        p.DisplayOrder++;
                    }

                    photo.DisplayOrder = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    var maxDisplayOrder = dbItem.Photos
                                                .Max(p => p.DisplayOrder);
                    photo.DisplayOrder = maxDisplayOrder + 1;
                }

                dbItem.Photos.Add(photo);
                Context.Users.Attach(dbItem);
                Context.Entry(dbItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
                return Context.Entry(dbItem).GetValidationResult().IsValid;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                   throw new DataRepositoryException(ex.InnerException.Message,
                              "UserDataRepository.InsertItem", 
                              ex.InnerException);

                throw new DataRepositoryException(ex.Message,
                          "UserDataRepository.InsertItem", 
                          ex);
            }
        }
```

The problem I have is that the validation returns IsValid = False for the user entity. I have checked and as soon as I retrieve it from the database, the IsValid = False for the user returned from the Find() operation, saying "Location field is required".

Location is a property of User, which is mandatory and references another table, called GeographicalLocation, so the Location property of the user should be a valid GeographicalLocation object.

I have checked using Watch and the User (when returned) definitely has a valid Location assigned to the Location property so I am confused why it is failing validation.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: User class below

```
[Table("User")]
    public class DbUser : IEntityComparable<DbUser>
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(80)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(80)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(80)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(1)]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual DbGeographicalArea Location { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the `User` class?

Comment: if dbItem does not include the GeographicalLocation object include it and try again

Comment: Added user class. A bit more debugging seems to show that if I debug through the code and open up the user variable and display the Location object contained within it, I can then run the code and it works. I'm guessing this is something to do with lazy loading? How do I specify in the above User class to not lazy load the GeographicalArea object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the `[Required]` data annotation from the the `Location` property and add a foreign key:

```
//You don't need a [Required] annotation on an int because it isn't nullable
public int LocationID {get; set;}

public virtual DbGeographicalArea Location { get; set; }
```

The `LocationID` is in the `Users` table so it will be populated without a join to the `DbGeographicalAreas` table - which is what happens if you use `Include`

Entity Framework is much easier to use if you add foreign keys.

References:

[Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

[Making Do with Absent Foreign Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx)